# Во Flutter есть возможность открыть html файл локально из ресурсов?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Если ли такая возможность во Flutter открыть файл html из ресурсов самого приложения, а не из сети ?
 - Суть вопроса : я пишу (offline) приложение книга рецептов (пока только под Андроид), там много текста и часто этот текст необходимо форматировать для красоты (шрифт, цвет, подчеркивание и прочее), удобно сделать тегами в html, а потом открывать в приложении.
Может что-то посоветуете, как по другому сделать приложение книгу если этот вариант не подходит ?
Спасибо ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Во Flutter есть возможность открыть html файл локально из ресурсов?

Во Flutter нет такой возможности, в Dart присутствует [инструменты для работы с html](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/dart-html-library.html). Есть альтернатива в виде использования библиотек под flutter, в свою очередь они помогут вам вставить ваш html файл в код проекта, вот некоторые из них:

1. [Html](https://pub.dev/packages/html)
2. [Flutter Html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)
3. [Flutter Widget from HTML](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html)

Ещё больше библиотек вы можете найти на [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=HTML)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/384007)

Comment: @nomnoms12 так лучше?